# Nested transform.position in Unity

Tags: unity, transformation

The following code works  so good , but it is so long.

How can I use a `for` loop to write a short script for any number of prefabs?

```
public GameObject prefab1;
public GameObject prefab2;
public GameObject prefab3;
float timCounter = 0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
  timCounter += Time.deltaTime;

  float[]  r = {3,2,1};
  float[]  f = {3,2,1};

  //motion on a circle

  float x = r[0] * Mathf.Cos(f[0] * timCounter);
  float y = r[0] * Mathf.Sin(f[0] * timCounter);

  float x1 = r[1] * Mathf.Cos(f[1] * timCounter);
  float y1 = r[1] * Mathf.Sin(f[1] * timCounter);

  float x2 = r[2] * Mathf.Cos(f[2] * timCounter);
  float y2 = r[2] * Mathf.Sin(f[2] * timCounter);

  float z = 0;

  //position of a any prefab_n = position of prefab_(n-1) + Vector3(x,y,z)

  prefab1.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);

  prefab2.transform.position = prefab1.transform.position + new 
  Vector3(x1,y1,z);

  prefab3.transform.position = prefab2.transform.position + new 
  Vector3(x2,y2,z);
 }
```

Comment: When you say "nested," are you using parenting at all here? ie. is `prefab3` a child of `prefab2` which in turn is a child of `prefab1`? Also, are these really "prefabs" (archetypal assets in your project folder), or "instances" (objects you've actually spawned into your scene)?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public GameObject[] prefabs;
public float[] r;
public float[] f;
float timeCounter = 0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    timeCounter += Time.deltaTime;

    var z = 0;
    var numPrefabs = prefabs.Length;
    var prevPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < numPrefabs; ++i)
    {
      var x = r[i] * Mathf.Cos(f[i] * timeCounter);
      var y = r[i] * Mathf.Sin(f[i] * timeCounter);
      var pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);

      prefabs[i].transform.position = prevPosition + pos;

      prevPosition = pos;
    }
}
```

Here we have an array of game objects to proceed. You should link them to your game objects in Unity Inspector as well as setup r array and f array. Then this script will iterate over all game objects and set a position like in your script.